# redirect url to other url 301 which has special character

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am new in .htaccess url redirect.

I want to redirect url to homepage or any other with 301 code which have an special character like `%` and a url which has two forward slash (//).

**I want to redirect this url to homepage**

> http://localhost/website/product/tropicana-100%-apple-juice-tetra-pack 
>   http://localhost/website/catalogsearch/result//jivaraj-mamari

I tried many answers but i didn't get what i want.
Please see above urls and suggest a possible ways.

any help would be highly appreciated.
**THANK YOU!**

**UPDATE**

I have this code in .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^category/energy-drinks-juices/sub-category-1$ category/energy-and-health-drinks [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} $ [NC]
RewriteRule ^category/home-care/filter/cat/(.*)$ / [L,R=301]
```

above redirect url code of .htaccess works perfectly.

but when i add

```
RewriteRule ^products/tropicana-100%-apple-juice-tetra-pack$ / [R=301,L]
```

or

```
RewriteRule ^catalogsearch/result//jivaraj-mamari$ / [R=301,L]
```

This both url not redirecting to homepage..

so how can i achieve this type of url to redirect to homepage

Comment: Show me your .htaccess file code .  And remove one slash in the url .

Comment: Use this redirect code in .htaccess fiel :- 

RewriteEngine on
Redirect 301 / Your site URl/

Comment: @NimeShPatel i added my .htaccess code.  but my question is how can i redirect those urls which has this type of special character in between url..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`RewriteCond` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) to check if the request URI contains these special characters, `//`, `%`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} //|\%
RewriteRule ^ / [R=301,L]
```

Comment: this work for url which has two time //. but it doesn't work for %. so you have any other idea on it

Comment: The `%` actually not allowed in URL according to RFC, the server will return 400 bad request because of malformed URL. See also: https://superuser.com/questions/759959/why-does-the-percent-sign-in-a-url-cause-an-http-400-bad-request-error

Comment: So that means i need to use "%25" instead of "%". thanks @ben